# ssl socket wrapper returns error on connect

Tags: python, ssl

When opening a ssl-wraped socket, I get the error `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:581)`

The server is running TLSv1.1

My code is

```
import socket, ssl
uw = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s = ssl.wrap_socket(uw, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1)
s.connect((host, port))
```

I can't figure it out. I've tried using a cacert file and get the same error.

```
s = ssl.wrap_socket(uw, ca_certs="cacert.pem", cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Found my problem: wrong port. I was connecting to the normal port and not the SSL-wrapped port.

Comment: Cool! So there is an app that listens for both: secured an non secured connections, on different ports... didn't expect that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the ssl socket, but the inner socket itself. So, when constructing the `uw` socket specify the family and the protocol like:

```
uw = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

Note that the above is just an example for TCP (`SOCK_STREAM`) sockets working on IPV4 (`AF_INET`) only.

Comment: Hmm, then the SSL protocol might be the problem. By default python's ssl uses SSLv23 version that works with almost any other version except SSLv2. Try using `s = ssl.wrap_socket(uw, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv2)`

Comment: hmm, now it is getting stuck on connect. Also the server only supports TLSv1.2 so SSLv23 should have worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. 
You should use port 443 for HTTPS.
I was still using port 80.

```
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
PORT = 443 
HOST = parsed.netloc
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s = ssl.wrap_socket(sock,ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23,ciphers="")
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

s.sendall('GET '+parsed.geturl()+ ' HTTP/1.1\r\n'\
        +'Host: '+HOST+'\r\n'
        +'\r\n')

data = ""
while True:
    res = s.recv(4096)
    if not res:
        break
    data += res 
s.close()
```